# Acquia BLT - How to put remote config_split config values back into version control

Tags: configuration, deployment, acquia-cloud

I have been using Acquia BLT and config split.

I understand how to set up the config splits and deploy them using BLT.

What I don't understand is - once I have a split in place, say on dev, and I've changed the configuration on dev... how do I get that changed configuration which is only in the dev database back into version control?

Doing a `cex` command on the Acquia server doesn't work - I get a long list of permission denied errors (presumably because without livedev mode on, the code on the Acquia server is read only).

```
...
[warning] unlink(/mnt/www/html/xxxx/config/default/workflows.workflow.editorial.yml): Permission denied FileSystem.php:124
 [error]  The file permissions could not be set on /mnt/www/html/xxxx/config/default.
```

So how can I export the config from dev once I've changed it, and get it into my version control system?

Addition: I am expecting that I would have my `/config/envs/{env}` directory on my local containing the remote yaml config files, so that I could track changes to the split configuration across environments. But maybe this isn't true?

Comment: With Acquia, you're not meant to change configuration remotely, other than for impermanent testing. The idea is you change the configuration locally, then deploy it with BLT, which will then install it on the remote server.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is get the relevant file's config on the server via `drush cget ...` or by alias and put it in the relevant split YAML in VCS. This assumes your split config doesn't cover a whole lot of configuration.

Comment: Interesting, thank you.